# str_replace: replacement depending on wildcard value [A-Z]

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a number of strings containing the pattern "of" followed by an uppercase letter without spaces (in regex: "of[A-Z]"). I want to add spaces, e.g. "PrinceofWales" should become "Prince of Wales" etc.). However, I couldn't find how to add the value of [A-Z] that was matched into the replacement value:

```
library(tidyverse) 

str_replace("PrinceofWales", "of[A-Z]", " of [A-Z]")
# Gives: Prince of [A-Z]ales
# Expected: Prince of Wales

str_replace("DukeofEdinburgh", "of[A-Z]", " of [A-Z]")
# Gives: Duke of [A-Z]dinburgh
# Expected: Duke of Edinburgh
```

Can someone enlighten me? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be captured as a group (`([A-Z])`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group i.e. `regex` interpretation is in the `pattern` and not in the `replacement`

```
stringr::str_replace("PrinceofWales", "of([A-Z])", " of \\1")
[1] "Prince of Wales"
```

According to `?str_replace`

> replacement - A character vector of replacements. Should be either length one, or the same length as string or pattern. References of the form \1, \2, etc will be replaced with the contents of the respective matched group (created by ()).

---

Or another option is a regex lookaround

```
stringr::str_replace("PrinceofWales", "of(?=[A-Z])", " of ")
[1] "Prince of Wales"
```